# How to solve $\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2e^x$

Tags: limits

How to solve the following limit?

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2e^x\\
> \end{eqnarray}

[image]

According to the website WolframAlpha, L'H rule can be used here but it is $-\infty/1$ instead of $-\infty/-\infty$, $\infty/\infty$ or $0/0$. So how to solve this question?

***Thank you for your attention***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:
Putting $y=-x,$  $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2e^x=\lim_{y\to\infty}y^2e^{-y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^2}{e^y}$$ which is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

So, apply L'H rule twice as the exponent of $y$ in the numerator is $2$

Comment: Finally, $2e^x$ and $e^x$ tend to 0, so the answer is 0...?

Comment: @CasperLi  any doubt? what is $\lim{r\to\infty}a^r$ if $a>1$

Comment: In the final step, I get $2/e^y$ and $2/\infty$, so...?

Comment: @CasperLi, http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/limits-infinity.html  and http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100306214353AAETJA6

Answer (score 2):

Simply recall that $e^t\ge 1+t$ for all $t$, hence for $t>0$ we have  $e^t=(e^{t/3})^3\ge (1+t)^3>t^3$. Thus for $x<0$
$$0<x^2e^x=\frac{x^2}{e^{|x|}}<\frac{x^2}{|x|^3}=\frac1{|x|}.$$