# question on limit

Tags: limits

How can I solve the limit of $\,\, N*a^N$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$ and $0<a<1$?

Comment: Have you already studied series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the ratio test gives us

$$\frac{(N+1)a^{N+1}}{Na^N}=\frac{N+1}Na\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{}a<1$$

and thus the series

$$\sum_{N=1}^\infty Na^N\;\;\;\text{converges, so it must be that}\;\;\;\lim_{N\to\infty}Na^N=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $b = -\ln a \gt 0\,$, and write the expression as $\frac{1}{b} \cdot \left(bN \,e^{-bN}\right)\,$. Then substitute $x=bN\,$, and use your favorite proof that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x e^{-x} = 0\,$, see e.g. [Formal proof for $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\exp(-x) =0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546781/formal-proof-for-lim-x-to-inftyx-exp-x-0).